# IE8 Debugging Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I wanted to find out what people use to debug Javascript IE8 and 9 on an application I'm developing on Localhost? Currently I am on a mac so don't have Internet Explorer at all.I have read that some people download VirtualBox for mac, and use 'localhost'  10.0.2.2 in internet explorer.

Another way is to copy paste my js code into JSLint and slowly debug any issues that come up in there.

What other approaches to people who are developing web applications use for IE? Are there any other tools?

Comment: If you're developing something specific to Windows, **get a Windows PC!** I used to work in a place, and in one of the offices, everyone had Macs because "they're cool". What were they developing? Windows software! So what did they do? Booted OS X, then booted Windows in a VM and worked from within the VM all day... wtf?! Doesn't make sense... not that I have anything against Macs; I love them!

Comment: its not specifically for Windows. I have made an application which works perfectly on ALL browsers except IE.... thus i know want to debug IE (i know its the javascript that's causing it errors...)

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll let you off! ;)

Comment: modern.ie you can download all versions of ie and virtual machines here.

Answer (score 2):

I have the opposite problem (as I develop in Windows and need to test Safari on Mac). Microsoft provides virtual machines running many IE versions: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

I believe there is a way to import these virtual hard drives into Parallels or VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

I guess modern Macs can run Windows side by side with OS X.

I would run a dual boot in order to fully support IE.